# Ansible variable has inconsistent values

Tags: ansible

I've been playing with ansible for the last couple of days and have run into a behavior that makes no sense to me. I can reproduce this with a simple playbook that runs two roles. Each role sets a variable, then imports a chain of other roles. The other roles do nothing but print out the value of the variable, then import the next role in the chain. The output I get is:

$ ansible-playbook site.yml

```
"msg": "role_1a v1 = role_1a default"
"msg": "role_2 v1 = role_1a default"
"msg": "role_3 v1 = role_1a default"
"msg": "role_4 v1 = role_1b default" <=== expected role_1a default
"msg": "role_5 v1 = role_1b default" <=== expected role_1a default

"msg": "role_1b v1 = role_1b default"
"msg": "role_2 v1 = role_1b default"
"msg": "role_3 v1 = role_1a default" <=== expected role_1b default
"msg": "role_4 v1 = role_1b default"
"msg": "role_5 v1 = role_1b default"
```

I've read the section on variables about twenty times now and the only thing I can see that may have a bearing on this is "Since Ansible 2.7 variables defined in vars and defaults for the role are
exposed at playbook parsing time", which I suppose could mean that variable inheritance at execution time is a crapshoot.

```
# site.yml
- hosts: testserver
  roles:
    - role_1a
    - role_1b

# roles/role_1a/defaults/main.yml
v1: "role_1a default"

# roles/role_1a/tasks/main.yml
- debug: msg="role_1a v1 = {{ v1 }}"
- import_role: name=role_2

# roles/role_2/tasks/main.yml
- debug: msg="role_2 v1 = {{ v1 }}"
- import_role: name=role_3

# roles/role_3/tasks/main.yml
- debug: msg="role_3 v1 = {{ v1 }}"
- import_role: name=role_4

# roles/role_4/tasks/main.yml
- debug: msg="role_4 v1 = {{ v1 }}"
- import_role: name=role_5

# roles/role_5/tasks/main.yml
- debug: msg="role_5 v1 = {{ v1 }}"

# roles/role_1b/defaults/main.yml
v1: "role_1b default"

# roles/role_1b/tasks/main.yml
- debug: msg="role_1b v1 = {{ v1 }}"
- import_role: name=role_2

# hosts
[testing]
testserver

# /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
[defaults]
[inventory]
[privilege_escalation]
[paramiko_connection]
[ssh_connection]
[persistent_connection]
[accelerate]
[selinux]
[colors]
[diff]

$ ansible --version
ansible 2.9.3
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/joe/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Aug  7 2019, 00:51:29) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
re
```

Comment: Not an answer, but I tested this quick, and I believe you are absolutely correct in your assumption about parsing of defaults.  Changing the variable in the `role_1b` default to `v2` makes it "work as expected".

Comment: There are two reasons why I am having difficulty with that explanation:
1. I have a hard time imagining a reasonable parse order that would produce this output.
2. It seems to me that it would make ansible variables useless. 

I searched extensively before posting the question and didn't find anything really resembling it. Because of that, and the fact that apparently everyone else seems to be able to use variables without issues, I am more inclined to believe that there is some fundamental concept I missed along the way.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"The fact that apparently everyone else seems to be able to use variables without issues, I am more inclined to believe that there is some fundamental concept I missed along the way."*

A: Not the case, unfortunately. Very probably it's an Ansible issue. There are a dozen [include and import issues](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/projects/19#card-9047818). Some of them are reminding the problem described here

- [Loss of variable value when include role depth exceed 3 #47023](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/47023)
- [Role included from two roles in playbook, but is run with last variable twice. #37787](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/37787)
- [Importing/Including a role does not overwrite the default values #39684](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/39684)

---

I was able to reproduce the reported result. The play

```
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - role_1a
    - role_1b
```

gives

```
    "msg": "role_1a v1 = role_1a default"
    "msg": "role_2 v1 = role_1a default"
    "msg": "role_3 v1 = role_1a default"
    "msg": "role_4 v1 = role_1b default"
    "msg": "role_5 v1 = role_1b default"
    "msg": "role_1b v1 = role_1b default"
    "msg": "role_2 v1 = role_1b default"
    "msg": "role_3 v1 = role_1a default"
    "msg": "role_4 v1 = role_1b default"
    "msg": "role_5 v1 = role_1b default"
```

Let's make sure the order of the messages is correct. Changed tasks (similar role_1a,2,3,4)

```
# roles/role_1b/tasks/main.yml
- debug: msg="role_1b v1 = {{ v1 }}"
- import_role:
    name: role_2
  vars:
    root: "role_1b"

# roles/role_5/tasks/main.yml
- debug: msg="root = {{ root }} | role_5 v1 = {{ v1 }}"
```

give

```
    "msg": "role_1a v1 = role_1a default"
    "msg": "root = role_1a | role_2 v1 = role_1a default"
    "msg": "root = role_1a | role_3 v1 = role_1a default"
    "msg": "root = role_1a | role_4 v1 = role_1b default"
    "msg": "root = role_1a | role_5 v1 = role_1b default"
    "msg": "role_1b v1 = role_1b default"
    "msg": "root = role_1b | role_2 v1 = role_1b default"
    "msg": "root = role_1b | role_3 v1 = role_1b default" <=== was: role_1a default
    "msg": "root = role_1b | role_4 v1 = role_1b default"
    "msg": "root = role_1b | role_5 v1 = role_1b default"
```

It shows the order of the messages is correct. But, the result changed. Now the result of `role_1b` is as expected.

---

> Q: *"Namespace the variables to avoid conflicts. What is namespacesing?"*

A: "Namespacing" means to "define the variable", or in particular "register the variable with the host", i.e. put the variable into the `hostvars`. For example

```
# roles/role_1a/tasks/main.yml
- set_fact:
    v1: "{{ v1 }}"
- debug: msg="role_1a v1 = {{ v1 }}"
- import_role:
    name: role_2
  vars:
    root: "role_1a"
```

gives as expected

```
    "msg": "role_1a v1 = role_1a default"
    "msg": "root = role_1a | role_2 v1 = role_1a default"
    "msg": "root = role_1a | role_3 v1 = role_1a default"
    "msg": "root = role_1a | role_4 v1 = role_1a default"
    "msg": "root = role_1a | role_5 v1 = role_1a default"
    "msg": "role_1b v1 = role_1a default"
    "msg": "root = role_1b | role_2 v1 = role_1a default"
    "msg": "root = role_1b | role_3 v1 = role_1a default"
    "msg": "root = role_1b | role_4 v1 = role_1a default"
    "msg": "root = role_1b | role_5 v1 = role_1a default"
```

because once the variable `v1` was defined in the scope of the paybook there is no need to look for the default. It should be noted that

```
- debug: msg="role_1a v1 = {{ v1 }}"
```

does not define the variable `v1`. This statement will only evaluate the variable `v1` on demand. Quoting from [Ansible Glosary](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#glossary):

> **Lazy Evaluation**: In general, Ansible evaluates any variables in playbook content at the last possible second, which means that if you define a data structure that data structure itself can define variable values within it, and everything “just works” as you would expect. This also means variable strings can include other variables inside of those strings.

The same result should be achieved with the changed order of the roles because all roles are imported.

```
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - role_1b
    - role_1a
```

gives

```
    "msg": "role_1b v1 = role_1b default" <=== expected role_1a default
    "msg": "root = role_1b | role_2 v1 = role_1b default" <=== expected role_1a default
    "msg": "root = role_1b | role_3 v1 = role_1b default" <=== expected role_1a default
    "msg": "root = role_1b | role_4 v1 = role_1a default"
    "msg": "root = role_1b | role_5 v1 = role_1a default"
    "msg": "role_1a v1 = role_1a default"
    "msg": "root = role_1a | role_2 v1 = role_1a default"
    "msg": "root = role_1a | role_3 v1 = role_1a default"
    "msg": "root = role_1a | role_4 v1 = role_1a default"
    "msg": "root = role_1a | role_5 v1 = role_1a default"
```

This shows that "namespasing" is probably needed all around the roles. For example

```
# roles/role_1b/tasks/main.yml
- set_fact:
    v1: "{{ v1 }}"
- debug: msg="role_1b v1 = {{ v1 }}"
- import_role:
    name: role_2
  vars:
    root: "role_1b"
```

works around the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the links and example. What I take from all this is that I cannot use defaults/vars with general purpose roles,
and this is by design.

Comment: Well, you can, but namespace them to avoid conflicts.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by namespacing. It would be helpful if you could give a small example or at least description on how to apply them to this issue.

Comment: Namespacing means to "register" the variable with the host, i.e. put the variable into the hostvars. For example set_fact: v1 = "{{ v1 }}" works around the problem.

Comment: So both of these workarounds behave as I had originally expected. I can even do the second one relatively cleanly by moving defaults/main.yml to tasks/defaults.yml with set_fact at the top, and then import it into the role. The problem is that this increases the precedence and I can no longer override with inventory or group variables.

As for the glossary item, it is not obvious to me how binding the variable when it is assigned would prevent doing the same thing. In any case this isn't likely to change and I think I am just whining now, so I really just wanted to thank you for your help.

Comment: You're missing the point, I think. Trivial assignment e.g. set_fact: v1 = "{{ v1 }}" creates [host level variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html#parameters) i.e.  put the variable into the hostvars. This works around the problem. It's not necessary to move defaults/main.yml to tasks/defaults.yml. Practically, "namespacing" means to "set_fact" in tasks/main.yml all variables that are used in the role. Tedious, but safe.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I understand. Moving the defaults is an aesthetic. It allows me to keep the concept of separating code and definition while (mostly) restoring what I consider proper behavior. I say mostly because I lose a chunk of my override capabilty (which is turning into a big problem), and have to add a few extra lines into every top-level role. If variable assignments were immediate and the recursive variable issue fixed I think it would be perfect for my needs. As it is I think I am going to have to explore using something else entirely. I do appreciate you following up though.